# javascript autocomplete close with a visual bug

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I was trying to close my autocomplete list in javascript if the user click somewhere else, and found this great answer: [Jquery Close autoComplete list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020199/jquery-close-autocomplete-list)

Since I do not have a "showmore" option like in the original question I adapted it as follow:

```
 $(document).bind('click', function (event) {
            $(".ui-menu-item").remove();
    });
```

However this code create a visual bug that you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: Visual bug screenshot]

And here is where in the code I added the block of code to handle closing the autocomplete:
https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/usf-mobullity/blob/mobullityrebase/src/client/js/otp/widgets/tripoptions/TripOptionsWidget.js#L294

I have tried to change `.ui-menu-item` to `.ui-menu` or `.ui-autocomplete` but these changed disabled the possibility to open the autocomplete list.

If you have an idea why there is this leftover of the autocomplete list and know how to fix it let me know. I assume it comes from `.ui-menu-item` but I'm not sure and what I have tried was unsuccessful.

Comment: you right click the letfover element and click inspect element (assuming chrome) and check the document structure and see what element is remaining (might be a parent element), may be you want to change your JS code to remove that element. also, just check if you actually need to remove it, or you can just hide it...

Comment: Why don´t you try to add dsiplay none to the element?

Comment: @redflar3 I did so and that's why I'm saying I tried `.ui-menu` and `.ui-autocomplete`. These tag are the one I can see from the inspector on the element remaining.

Comment: @JorgeMejia I'm sorry but I'm fairly new to javascript so I don't understand what you mean. Can you expand a bit, pls?

Comment: @redflar3 I was trying hide() instead and it is working on `.ui-menu` thanks a lot.

Comment: display is a css property and Jorge is asking you to set that to none, which  is the same thing that jquery is doing for you when you use `hide`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the element to be used in future, You should try to `hide` the element instead of removing it. Also since changing remove to hide worked, so adding this answer just for the record.