# How to detect a click outside autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have the following JQuery to display an autocomplete list:

```
var displayNum = 10;
var pointer = displayNum;

function DelegateSearch(txtBox)
{   
$("#" + txtBox).attr("placeholder", "Search by Last Name");

$(".ajaxcompanyRefreshImage").attr("src", "/images/refresh.jpg");
$(".ajaxcompanyRefreshImage").hide();

$("#" +txtBox).parents().find('.ajaxcompanyRefreshImage').click(function () { $("#" +txtBox).autocomplete("search"); });

$("#" +txtBox).dblclick(function () { $(this).autocomplete("search"); });
$("#" +txtBox).autocomplete({
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).parents().find('.ajaxcompanyRefreshImage').hide();
        }
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {             
        var addr = ui.item.value.split('-');

        var label = addr[0];
        var value = addr[1];
        value += addr[2];

        if (label == null || label[1] == null  ||(label.length < 1 && value == '' && value.length < 1)) {

            $(this).autocomplete("option", "readyforClose", false);
        }
        else {
            if (value[1]!= 0) {
                $(this).autocomplete("option", "readyforClose", true);
                delegateSearchPostBack(value, label, txtBox);
            }

        }              
        return false;
    },
    response: function (event, ui) {

        var more = { label : "<b><a href='javascript:showmoreNames();' id='showmore'>Show more Names...</a></b>", value: '' };
        ui.content.splice(ui.content.length, 0, more);
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {

        showmoreNames();
    },
    search : function (event, ui) {
        if ($(this).val().length < 3) {
            $(this).parents().find('.ajaxcompanyRefreshImage').hide();
            return false;
        }


        $(".ui-menu-item").remove();

    },
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/ajaxservice.asmx/GetDelegateListBySearch",
            data: "{ prefixText: " + "'" +request.term + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) {
                return data; },
            minLength: 2,
            success: function (data) {
                pointer = displayNum;
                response($.map(data.d, function (val, key) {
                    return {
                        label: DelegateSearchMenulayout(key, val),
                        value: val
                    };
                }));

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
        });
    }

});
}

function DelegateSearchMenulayout(key, val) {

var net = '';
var userData = val.split('-');

var table = "<table width=350px' style='border-bottom-style:solid;'    class='menutable'>";
table += "<tr><th width='300px'></th>";
table += "<tr><td><b>" + userData[1] + "" + userData[2] + "</b></td></tr>";
table += "<tr><td>" + userData[4] + " - " + userData[3] + "</td></tr>";
   table += "</table>";

return table;
}

function delegateSearchPostBack(userName, userId, txtBox) {   
$("#" + txtBox).autocomplete("destroy");
$("#" + txtBox).val(userId +"-" + userName );
pointer = displayNum;    
__doPostBack(txtBox, "");
}

function showmoreNames() {
$(".menutable").each(function (index) {
 if (index >= pointer) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
}
else {
    $(this).parent().show();
}
});

if ($(".menutable").length <= pointer) {
$("#showmore").attr("href", "javascript: function () {return false;}");
$("#showmore").text("End of Users");
}
else pointer += displayNum;
}
```

It displays 10 names by default. If the list is longer, "Show more names" is displayed on click of which,10 more names are displayed. With the initial 10 names, the JQuery works perfect.If I click outside or hit ESC, the autocomplete  disappears. But with a result set containing more than 10 names, when I click on Show More Names, the next 10 names are displayeda but on click of ESC or clicking outside the list, it does not disappear! How can I make this work? The close event is not triggered in this case.
I tried the following solution: [how to make the dropdown autocomplete to disappear onblur or click outside in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182559/how-to-make-the-dropdown-autocomplete-to-disappear-onblur-or-click-outside-in-jq) But with this solution, the list disappears when I click on Show More! How do I detect whether the click outside the autocomplete?
Update: I just noticed while debugging that when I click outside, the close event should be triggered, but in this case this doesn't happen, hence the autocomplete does not close!

Comment: Can include `html` at OP , create stacksnippets , http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 $(document).bind('click', function (event) {
        // Check if we have not clicked on the search box
        if (!($(event.target).parents().andSelf().is('#showmore'))) {
            $(".ui-menu-item").remove();
```